# Determining Whether Correct Credentials Submitted through Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I'm building a UI to have a user sign-in to their financial institution using the Yodlee REST API, using the *site-based APIs*.

It seems the only way to determine whether the user submitted correct credentials is to poll the `getSiteRefreshInfo` API for a "while" and see if a 402 error comes back in the refresh status.

Is this indeed the only way to achieve this or is there a more elegant and deterministic way?

Answer (score 1):

In short this is the only way to determine whether the credentials submitted are correct or not. To explain you in more detail about what happens when you submit credentials.

1. You call addSiteAccount1 API and submit the credentials to Yodlee.
2. Yodlee will use the credentials and try to login on behalf of user(submitting the credentials to the specific Bank site).
3. Bank website validate the credentials and provide a response either with a successful login or with an error message.
4. Yodlee checks the response and let you know the result as the response of getSiteRefreshInfo API, in case of invalid credentials you'll get 402.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea what's a good period of time to wait before concluding that if a 402 error didn't return so far - the credentials are ok?

Comment: Generally, it varies from 10- 50 secs(excluding edge cases-where site is very slow in providing response). In case where credentials are valid you'll receive LOGIN_SUCCESS in the API response.

Comment: Thanks!There will be a LOGIN_SUCCESS in response to which API method? I've never seen one of those. I only either see a login failure (error code 402) or "refresh triggered" status.

Comment: You need to poll the getSiteRefreshInfo API, you can check the API flow present over here. https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account